# Facebook Timeline: How to post more than one picture (or video) per post?

Tags: facebook, video, images, facebook-timeline

This may seem like a very simple question: I can see that some of my friends are able to post more than one picture (or video) per post on the Timeline, but when I try to do the same thing, I click on the Image link at the top of the New Post box and then click on the Plus Sign to insert an image from the PC. Once I do this I am not able to insert any other images or videos (I don't see where I can do this).

How can I accomplish inserting more than one image or video in the same post?

Comment: You’ve seen [this help page](https://www.facebook.com/help/community/question/?id=10201458592576373), right?

Comment: Why don't you create an album and then share it?

Comment: Also, you know you can select more than one picture from the dialog box, right?

Comment: Thank you all for your replies. It seems that when I post to my own Timeline I can post more than one picture, but when I post on someone else's timeline I can post only one picture. What a drawback. Never mind.

Answer (score 1):

As explained in the comments, multiple photo posting at the time was only available to the user's own timeline not friends (which can only post one at a time)

Another way to achieve this will be to post to your own timeline and tag the friend in the message body based on the friend tag review settings it will appear on his/her timeline as well.